# Apache 2.4 SSLSessionCache missed

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-ssl

Apache server is behind a physical loadbalancer et it uses an https connection between.
The loadbalance break the https en create a new https connexion with apache.

So it's always the same client that makes calls to the apache server.

But in my serveur status I see that the cache is actived but SSL session are never retrieves from cache it always miss.

[image]

Why ? Because I imagine that configuration with the loadbalance will make only one SSL sesssion reused in each connection.

Update :
Production trafic is send to this server :
[image]

There is some hit but the cache seems not be used

Comment: I guess that depends if the balancer supports SSL Session resumption. Which probably wont, or not using it. I would check that first.

Comment: @erza Yes I think so. But I make test with firefow direct to apache (by passing loadbalancer) and I don't increase "hits", and I wait between request to avoid keepalive connection.